# Battery capacity vs LED consumption

Tags: batteries

I have an ESP32 circuit that works basically as LED dimmer. The circuit will be used as a portable device, hence the battery.

There are 3 groups of LEDs: each group consist of six 5730 SMD LEDs. If all 3 groups are on that's a total of 18 LEDs.

5730 LED each draws 150 m, so 18 x 150 = 2700 mA.

If I use four 18650 cells (parallel) which are typically rated at 2000mAh, how long will this device stay on?

My calculation: 4x2000 / 2700 * 1hr = 3 hr (I'm aware power for the ESP32 circuit has not been factored in.)

Is this correct?

Comment: How will the LEDs be connected?  If they are in series then they won't light at all.

Comment: Be very careful connecting lithium cells in parallel. If they are not **exactly** the same you could have dangerously large current flowing between them.

Comment: @JRE why? If the voltage matches the sum of all LEDs why won't it?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I somewhat understand the concept of matching cells back from RC days. You said dangerously?

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on how you power the LEDs. Do you use resistors to limit current, or is there some switching supply to lower the voltage?

If you take for example 10V source and load that draws 1 amp, it would draw 1A from the source (1Ah battery would last 1 hour). But if the voltage is first stepped down to 5V, it would draw only 0.5 amps from the source (if the conversion from 10 to 5 V was 100% efficient). Power on input and output is same, so $$ V_1 \cdot I_1 = V_2 \cdot I_2$$

This is not the case for linear regulators (like the one that converts \$V_{in}\$ to 3.3V on ESP board). This type of regulator has same current on input and output, \$(U_1 - U_2)\cdot I\$ is dissipated as heat.

Using a resistor to limit the current through a LED is essentially a linear regulator.

If your 4 batteries are in parallel and you use no switching supply to lower the voltage, then your calculation is correct.

Consumption of the ESP is somewhere in 10s to 100s mA depending on active peripherals.

Comment: As I mentioned, ESP32 will control brightness of the 3 LED panels individually. I know I'll be using PWM for that, though I haven't researched how to deal with current limit on the PWM pins of the ESP32 which I believe only 30mA and 1200mA total. That would be another topic wouldn't it.
What voltage is the 5730 is rated at? 5V? If that's the case 150mA at 5V is  200mA at 3.7V (18650) right? I'm not EE as you can tell, only DIY person.
So I think I will have to find a way to step up the voltage output of the ESP32 PWM pins as well as current limit.

Answer (score 0):

That calculation assumes the voltage used to feed the led circuit is the same as the cell voltage. If you are using current regulators to drop the cell voltage to what the leds need (thus keeping a constant current over the cell discharge voltage 4.2-3V) this calculation holds up. Just a series resistor to regulate the current will cause the led current to shift slightly during discharge. If you calculated 2700mA at the max. cell voltage of 4.2V it could deviate quite noticeably, introducing error in your calculation.

Also be aware that at low led voltages (around 2V) you are wasting a LOT of energy by doing things linearly, and for higher led voltages you can potentially not use the full cell capacity without making the leds appear noticeably dimmer. If you are driving a few watts of leds it might be worthwhile to invest in a DC/DC converter if you haven't already. The leds in that case can be put in series. Wiring the batteries up series as well (2S2P or 4S1P) might also help. It lowers the current needed by the DC/DC (lower losses) and might enable you to use a step-down converter instead of step-up. Charging and cell protection will be more difficult on the other hand.

When using a DC/DC converter the calculation can be done differently. Instead of working just with the current consumption, calculate the energy (Wh) consumption of your led circuit, calculate the energy available in the battery (usually provided in datasheet) and finally factor in the DC/DC converter inefficiency.

Comment: Thanks. I somehow get the idea what you're saying.  At least you help me realize I don't have enough knowledge to built this myself, not in timely manner. LOL. I learned some things though. I think I'll hire someone for this. My original question is answered despite oversimplified. I was really just trying to decide how many batteries I need to make room for in the casing design. Thanks Y'all.

Comment: @10davvid "5730" is not an specific led, but a reference to the physical size of it. Let's use generic figures of 3.4V@150mA for a generic white LED. So that's 9.18Wh for 18 leds. Add 10% for expected losses in dc/dc voltage conversion. Samsung ICR18650-26F holds 2.6Ah from 4.2-2.75V with nominal 3.6V, so 9.36Wh. four of those cells will last 3.7 hours. High capacity (but expensive) types like Panasonic NCR18650B (3.25Ah, 11.7Wh), will last up to 4.6 hours

Comment: This is assuming a well designed boost converter to 21 or-so volts to drive 6 leds in series at once. Also don't drive directly with ESP32, it is too fragile to be handling so much current. You don't want to step up the supply voltage of the ESP32 signal, since it should not be providing the power in the first place. Use an external electronic switch to interrupt or allow the current to flow trough the leds, but make sure that current is being generated by a capable, separate, power supply (not ESP32). This can usually be done with a DC/DC converter. Some are made specifically to drive leds

Comment: Thanks for the education. You confirmed my logic. I realized I oversimplified. 
Yes, I understand now that there needs to be a converter circuit to drive the LEDs.
You seem inclined putting the LEDs in series, is that a more common way in this case?

Comment: If you have the chance to put the lithium cells in series, I would boost the pack voltage up a few volts to 21V, and then drive 6 leds at once with one current limiting resistor (x3). Even better is to design a constant current driver to avoid resistors all together. But that is adding a *lot* of cost and complexity. If battery life is not your absolute top priority, it is totally fine to put the cells in parallel and use a single buck/boost converter to convert to 4V. Now use a 4Ohm series resistor for each led. Way easier! But it's wasting an additional (0.15^2)*4*18 = 1.62W of power